# Having trouble with form inheritance in Odoo

Tags: odoo

I've been raking my head around this for the better part of the day and i just can't seem to get it right.

I'm trying to add a new field to the res_users form but whatever I do it just won't show. No errors, everything seems normal but the field just isn't showing in the form.

**manifest**.py:

```
{
    'name': "Extended User",
    'version': '1.0',
    'depends': ['base'],
    'author': "blake_won",
    'category': 'custom',
    'description': """
    Description text
    """,
    # data files always loaded at installation
    'data': [
        'views/extended_views.xml',
    ],
}
```

views file:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="res_users_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.users.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
                <group>
                <field name="extended_variable"></field>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

extendeduser.py:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class extendedUser(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users' 
    extended_variable = fields.Char(string="EXTENDED VARIABLE",default="NA")
```

console log:

````
2021-09-08 15:35:14,386 55731 INFO mydb odoo.modules.loading: Loading module extended_user (2/8) 
2021-09-08 15:35:14,411 55731 INFO mydb odoo.modules.registry: module extended_user: creating or updating database tables 
2021-09-08 15:35:14,484 55731 INFO mydb odoo.modules.loading: loading extended_user/views/extended_views.xml```


Please help me, i'm at my wit's end
````

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/developer/reference/views.html#inheritance-specs):

> An `xpath` element with an `expr` attribute. `expr` is an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression[2](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/developer/reference/views.html#hasclass) applied to the current arch, the first node it finds is the match

Odoo will find the first `partner_id` field, which is before the image field, and the `div` containing that field will be invisible if the current user and its related partner are active.

If you check the page source code, you will find after a hyperlink named `partner_id` something similar to:

```
<table class="o_group o_inner_group">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="o_td_label">
        <label class="o_form_label" for="o_field_input_710" data-original-title="" title="">EXTENDED VARIABLE</label>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="o_field_char o_field_widget" name="extended_variable">NA</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which is the rendered group

You can try to match the second `partner_id` field, which is inside a `group` inside a `div` that has a class named `oe_title`.

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('oe_title')]/group/field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
    <field name="extended_variable"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.
Have my upvote good sir